# How change req.param if req.param === undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using the following route that receives a param in the url:

```
app.get('/:lang', function(req, res) {

});
```

I will push the value of lang and send to a function, but i want be able to only use / if the user dont type any param.

I was trying:

```
if (req.param('lang') === undefined) {
 req.param('lang') = 'pt';
});
```

But.. GET / 404 2ms - does not exist..

Comment: This might be unrelated, but you can change this to something like: `var lang = req.param('lang') || 'pt';`

Comment: but the url does not change, still 404..

Comment: i need change the lang in the url.. if i don't receive anything as parameter, use /..

Comment: i am sorry, i dont get it.. req is defined inside the route. @Paul

Comment: if i put console.log(req.param('lang')); inside my route and try localhost:3000/en, will print 'en' in the terminal.

Comment: oh, i am sorry.. this is a typo in the post, in the code is fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your never getting to that route handler because the '/' route won't match, you have to use optional parameters in your case. Consider the following.

```
 app.use('/:lang?', function (req, res) {
    var lang = req.params.lang || 'pt';
    // do your stuff with the lang var
  });
```

and check out the [express docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html)

Comment: Nice! Working 100%.. Can i please ask you something? If i use req.param('lang') = req.param('lang') || 'pt'; doesn't work.. Why??? haha

Comment: Im suprised your not getting an error trying to do that. Your invoking a function thats returning the value for `req.param.lang` you cant assign that way. You should be getting an `invalid left hand assignment` error.

Comment: this error does not appear , but now I noticed that I get stuck in the 'pt'. hahaha

Comment: `req.params` is an object, and `req.param` is a function to access properties of `req.params`. To assign you have to use `req.params`

Comment: Hi , 
Suppose "/mobile/custom/******/deviceVersion/:deviceType" is my request .
could you please tell me how to check "deviceType" against undefined?